# Issues with ReactToPrint Library and Layout for Thermal Printer

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently working on a React.js project where I'm utilizing the ReactToPrint library to print a specific section of my page. However, I've encountered an issue where the page size remains significantly large, and a considerable amount of content is not captured in the receipt.

I suspect that the current layout might not be suitable for a thermal printer. I would greatly appreciate any assistance or recommendations on how I can optimize the layout of my receipt to better suit a thermal printer.

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
const [isPrintingReceipt, setIsPrintingReceipt] = useState(false);
const contentToPrintReceiptRef = useRef(null);
const onBeforeGetContentReceiptResolve = useRef(null);

const handlePrintReceipt = useReactToPrint({
  content: () => contentToPrintReceiptRef.current,
  pageStyle: `@media print {
    @page {
      size: 2.5in 4in,
    }
  }`,
  documentTitle: `Invoice`,
  onBeforeGetContent: () =>
    new Promise((resolve) => {
      if (patient && bill) {
        onBeforeGetContentReceiptResolve.current = resolve;
        setIsPrintingReceipt(true);
      }
    }),
  onAfterPrint: () => {
    onBeforeGetContentReceiptResolve.current = null;
    setIsPrintingReceipt(false);
  },
});

useEffect(() => {
  if (isPrintingReceipt && onBeforeGetContentReceiptResolve.current) {
    onBeforeGetContentReceiptResolve.current();
  }
}, [isPrintingReceipt]);

return (
<div ref={contentToPrintReceiptRef} className={isPrintingReceipt === true ? '' : styles.printContainer}>
    <PrintableReceipt bill={bill} patient={patient} isLoading={isLoading} />
</div>
);
```

[image: current print]

Answer (score 0):

I resulted to printing the receipt from the backend using nodejs, its easier to set the width of the print paper